# Will Bluetooth speakers and/or USB speakers work for sound when there is a broken headphone jack stuck in my macbook port?

Tags: audio, usb, bluetooth, headphones, speakers

I bought a Macbook for a low price because it has a headphone jack broken off in its port. I have tried some of the fixes for removing the jack, but it is broken deep in the port and unfortunately didn't come out in one clean piece. I would really like to be able to have some sort of audio, and I'm willing to buy Bluetooth speakers or speakers that plug into the USB, but first I want to know whether they will override the headphone port.

Also, the volume control on the menu is greyed out so I can't control volume. I have read that you can fix that by removing and reinserting your headphone jack, but I obviously can't do that here.

Does anyone know whether that will prevent me from using other speakers?

[[image]]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpOqg.png)

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of your System Preferences > Sounds > Output area?

Comment: I added 2 because I wasn't sure which one you meant. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, a Bluetooth and/or a USB speaker will "override" your audio input.**  It all depends on how you configure it.

In System Preferences > Sound, you can setup which audio device does what.

For example, in my setup, I play all the "Sound Effects" through the Internal Speakers, however, I could select the USB Audio device I also have installed.  For your case, you would select either the USB/Bluetooth Device.

[image]

You could even use both a Bluetooth audio device ***and*** a USB device

For example, in my Output configuration, I can choose Internal, USB Audio, or Bluetooth

[image]

And...

Depending on your Application, it can even select which audio device to use for it's individual output.  Here's the configuration screen from [VOX](http://coppertino.com/):

[image]

Comment: I would not say override but just that you can choose it